# How to solve this complicated loop issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, sorry for the title but I really don't know how to put this issue in one line but since its a loop issue I mentioned the same. I have been trying to figure out how to make this work but everything is going in vain, if am able to fix something another issue would come up.

I want to first read from a file and then print this way. (I would be using `+` instead of the word `concatenation` while explaining

First line I want it to be `input` + the **first line** of `myfile.txt` + `some_string` since this won't be possible because we are using `j` in code I have added `""` (which means nothing) in `num` and `chars` (this line is basically concatenating everything)

Second line I want it to be `input` + `2` + the **first line** of  `myfile.txt` + `2` + `some_string`

Third line I want it to be `input` +  `3` the **first line** of  `myfile.txt` + `3` + `some_string`

(the real problem starts after this)

Now from forth line I want to iterate the `chars` array as well and that's the one causing problem for me.

Forth line I want it to be `input` +  the **first line** of  `myfile.txt` + `ab` (from `chars` array) + `some_string` (this line is basically concatenating everything similar to first line but with `ab` from `chars`)

Fifth line I want it to be `input` +  `2` + the **first line** of  `myfile.txt` + `2`+ `ab`
 + `some_string`

Sixth line I want it to be `input` +  `3` + the **first line** of  `myfile.txt` + `3`+ `ab`
 + `some_string`

Seventh line I want it to be `input` +  the **first line** of  `myfile.txt` + `bc` + `some_string`

Eighth line I want it to be `input` +  `2` + the **first line** of  `myfile.txt` + `2`+ `bc`
 + `some_string`

Ninth line I want it to be `input` +  `3` + the **first line** of  `myfile.txt` + `3`+ `bc`
 + `some_string`

Then it will keep doing for entire char array ( `cd` , `de`, `ef` ) and after that it would do the exact same thing for **second line** of `myfile.txt`

The problem am facing is, `num` array and `chars` array are unequal (not with same index) so when I am iterating in `j` it is messing everything, whenever I fix one thing it would mess another for me. I have tried everything I can do in my capacity to deal with this but couldn't. Please let me know if I missed to explain anything.

```
num = ["", "2", "3"]

chars = ["ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "ef"]

some_string = "some_string"

input = str(input("input that we would get"))

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for i in myfile:
        for j in range(0,5):
            print(input + i.rstrip() + num[j] + chars[j] + some_string)
```

EDIT:

Someone pointed out that I should also show the expected output, here it is.

```
inputfileonesomestring
input2fileone2somestring
input3fileone3somestring
inputfileoneabsomestring
input2fileone2absomestring
input3fileone3absomestring
inputfileonebcsomestring
input2fileone2bcsomestring
input3fileone3bcsomestring
inputfileonecdsomestring
input2fileone2cdsomestring
input3fileone3cdsomestring
inputfileonedesomestring
input2fileone2desomestring
input3fileone3desomestring
inputfileoneefsomestring
input2fileone2efsomestring
input3fileone3efsomestring
inputfiletwosomestring
input2filetwo2somestring
input3filetwo3somestring
inputfiletwoabsomestring
input2filetwo2absomestring
input3filetwo3absomestring
inputfiletwobcsomestring
input2filetwo2bcsomestring
input3filetwo3bcsomestring
inputfiletwocdsomestring
input2filetwo2cdsomestring
input3filetwo3cdsomestring
inputfiletwodesomestring
input2filetwo2desomestring
input3filetwo3desomestring
inputfiletwoefsomestring
input2filetwo2efsomestring
input3filetwo3efsomestring
inputfilethreesomestring
input2filethree2somestring
input3filethree3somestring
inputfilethreeabsomestring
input2filethree2absomestring
input3filethree3absomestring
inputfilethreebcsomestring
input2filethree2bcsomestring
input3filethree3bcsomestring
inputfilethreecdsomestring
input2filethree2cdsomestring
input3filethree3cdsomestring
inputfilethreedesomestring
input2filethree2desomestring
input3filethree3desomestring
inputfilethreeefsomestring
input2filethree2efsomestring
input3filethree3efsomestring
```

Contents of myfile.txt

```
fileone
filetwo
filethree
```

Comment: This question would be a lot clearer if you gave a complete example and wrote the expected output for it, instead of describing how each line of the output should be constructed from the input. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That's for pointing it, let me update the question.

Comment: Can you help now?

Comment: What are the contents of `myfile`? To be a reproducible example you need to provide values for all of the inputs. This also doesn't look like a complete expected output because it doesn't include e.g. the string `bc`.

Comment: I have mentioned that it would then be same for `bc` etc still wait let me update it for the last time and I swear you won't have any issue now. :) just one min.

Comment: I have updated. I hope you don't face any issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace num with a python cycle from itertools and call next on it.

E.g. create your cycle as

```
import itertools
num=itertools.cycle(["","2","3"])
```

Then call next inside your loop instead of indexing

```
next(num)
```

EDIT:
The question edits makes it a bit clearer. 
You can use nested for loops to make it simpler.

```
for c in chars:
    for n in num:
       print(input + i.rstrip() + n + c + some_string)
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem - the wrong range of indices is being used in the list, and wrapping around cyclically won't achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand your description of the problem, but I think what you are trying to do is this:

- For each line of the file,

  - For an empty string and then for each value in `chars`,

    - For each value of `num`,

      - Print some output string formed by joining these things together.

Since there are three layers of repetition, the natural solution is to use three loops. The loop over `chars` will be simplified if you put an empty string at the start of that list:

```py
num = ["", "2", "3"]

# added empty string here
chars = ["", "ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "ef"]

some_string = "some_string"

input_string = str(input("input that we would get"))

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for file_line in myfile:
        file_line = file_line.rstrip()
        for c in chars:
            for n in num:
                print(input_string + n + file_line + n + c + some_string)
```

Note that I've renamed your `input` variable to avoid overwriting the built-in `input` function. I've also iterated over these lists by value, which is simpler and cleaner than iterating by index; and I've moved the `rstrip()` to the outer loop so that each line only has to be stripped once.

If you prefer not to have so many nested loops, an equivalent version can be written with one loop, using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
import itertools

num = ["", "2", "3"]
chars = ["", "ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "ef"]
some_string = "some_string"
input_string = str(input("input that we would get"))

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    myfile = ( s.rstrip() for s in myfile )
    for file_line, c, n in itertools.product(myfile, chars, num):
        print(input_string + n + file_line + n + c + some_string)
```

Comment: Am reading this comment, meanwhile you can check the updated question. :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help but its not giving desired output. (as already edited in the question) I checked without itertools.

Comment: Oh, I guess it's because you want the num and chars loops in the opposite order. But it would help if you were more specific about how the output differed from your desired output.

Comment: Output that am getting with your code won't properly fit here in the comment box.

Comment: I've edited to switch the order of those two loops, and I also noticed you are adding the string from `num` twice, so I edited that too. My output now matches yours as far as I can tell; if it doesn't, please give the first line on which they are different.

Comment: Hey your output seems correct, can you tell how to do it if we want `input2fileonesomestring` instead of `input2fileone2somestring` and `input3fileonesomestring` instead of `input3fileone3somestring` Its in second and third line in my output. And similarly for filetwo and filethree variant. It's not possible to add here in comment box so am add a paste bin link.https://pastebin.com/YGzR9K3n I have commented the chances from this output I mentioned in question and output there.

Comment: If the output is correct then I've answered the question, and what you're asking now is a different question. I don't follow from your example what you actually want, but it seems clear there are two different kinds of line you want to print (some with two numbers, some without), so you probably need two different print statements.

Comment: Actually the output I am looking for now is the real output I wanted. I was trying so many times to solve this mess that I ended up posting something which is bit wrong here. I am really sorry for posting something which is bit different than what I actually needed. But that print issue in second and third line of every line from file (fileone, filetwo, filethree) was the main issue which made it tough for me to solve it.

Comment: Should I post a new question? Can you help then?

Comment: I have answered the question you posted. I am not interested in continually updating my answer to reflect changes in the question, and the same applies whether you post the change as a new question or not. It's not fair on those who answer questions on Stack Overflow to move the goalposts like this after your question has already been answered, and in future you will have to be more careful to provide a **correct** example output for your own question. Hopefully you will be able to adapt the code in my answer to meet your real need.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But its really tough for me to just not print number two times in those specific lines. Please consider my genuine request for the last time. Even if you don't that's fine. Mistake was from my end. I would probably have to ask on some other platform or post here as a different question. Thanks once again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation doesn't have usage of numeric indices:

```
num = ["", "2", "3"]
chars = ["", "ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "ef"]
num_chars_variations=[(n, c) for c in chars for n in num]
some_string = "some_string"
input = str(input("input that we would get"))
with open("24_st.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        for variation in num_chars_variations:
            n, c = variation
            n1 = n if c != "" else ""
            print(input + n + line.strip() + n1 + c + some_string)
```

Comment: Nope. it is giving wrong output. I have mentioned the desired output in the question. Output that am getting with your code won't properly fit here in the comment box.

Comment: Sure, I forgot number in the last line: `print(input + n + line.strip() + n + c + some_string)`

Comment: Actually I messed up, I wanted output to be this way. Can you help? Since its not possible to properly enter in comment box am sharing it via pastebin. https://pastebin.com/YGzR9K3n

Comment: I have highlighted the chances from this output as comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Can you please explain `num_chars_variations=[(n, c) for c in chars for n in num]`and ` n1 = n if c != "" else "" `

Comment: first operator is a list comprehension - it's result is similar to `itertools` options posted in other answers. `n1 = n if c != "" else ""` is another python way to write `if` `else` operators. It will print `""` instead of second number if current char is `""`

Comment: You first assigned `n` to `n1` and then check if `c` is not equals to "" after it I don't get it. What is this way of if else called? Can you share a reference from where I can learn this.

Comment: [Short Hand If ... Else](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

Answer (score -1):

The tools you want here are the modulo operator and the integer division operator. Maybe something like this:

```
print(input + i.rstrip() + num[j%3] + chars[j//3] + some_string)
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem - the wrong range of indices is being used in the list, and wrapping around cyclically won't achieve the desired output.